# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

Getting the error for executing the following query:

```
UPDATE ETA.dbo.GK_Tasks 
SET TaskName='Identify appropriate tests/coverage', 
  Assignee='Linda/Cathy/testing', 
  StartDate='', 
  AntpCompleteDate='2014-01-10 00:00:00.0', 
  ActlComplDate='', 
  Status='Setup meeting with Linda/Cathy to review existing scripts and identify any additional required scripts', 
  Notes='Critical task to ensure that the automated tests are successful in capturing critical defects', 
  TaskSortID='1' 
WHERE ID='1', ProgramID='1', InitativeID='4'
```

I am pretty new to SQL query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `AND` in between each of your `WHERE` clause conditions. If you have multiple conditions you will use either `AND`/`OR` - you don't use commas between the conditions.

Instead of this:

```
WHERE ID='1', ProgramID='1', InitativeID='4'
```

You need to use:

```
WHERE ID='1' 
  AND ProgramID='1'
  AND InitativeID='4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

`WHERE ID='1' AND ProgramID='1' AND InitativeID='4'`